# Recording audio in "if" condition results in static

Tags: python, alsa

My goal is to record sound while a button is being pressed.

The first step was actually recording audio. The following script works like a charm:

```
import alsaaudio, wave, numpy

inp = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE, alsaaudio.PCM_NORMAL, "default:CARD=C525")
inp.setchannels(1)
inp.setrate(44100)
inp.setformat(alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)
inp.setperiodsize(1024)

w = wave.open('test.wav', 'w')
w.setnchannels(1)
w.setsampwidth(2)
w.setframerate(44100)

while True:
    l, data = inp.read()
    a = numpy.fromstring(data, dtype='int16')
    print numpy.abs(a).mean()
    w.writeframes(data)
```

The test.wav file plays like a charm and the sound is properly being recorded.

Now I want to only record audio while a button is pressed. I am using the GrovePi with a button. The button works great. It detects the button being pressed, it generates the .wav file, but the audio file it generates contains pure static.

```
import time
import grovepi
import alsaaudio
import os
import wave
import numpy

button = 4 #grovepi D4
grovepi.pinMode(button,"INPUT")
inputSoundDevice = "default:CARD=C525"
path = os.path.realpath(__file__).rstrip(os.path.basename(__file__))

def start():
    print "started"

    while True:
        if grovepi.digitalRead(button) == 1:
            inp = alsaaudio.PCM(alsaaudio.PCM_CAPTURE, alsaaudio.PCM_NORMAL, inputSoundDevice)
            inp.setchannels(1)
            inp.setrate(44100)
            inp.setformat(alsaaudio.PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)
            inp.setperiodsize(1024)
            time.sleep(.5)
            print "inp setup"

            w = wave.open('test.wav', 'w')
            w.setnchannels(1)
            w.setsampwidth(2)
            w.setframerate(44100)
            print "wave setup"

            while(grovepi.digitalRead(button) == 1):
                l, data = inp.read()
                a = numpy.fromstring(data, dtype='int16')
                print numpy.abs(a).mean()
                w.writeframes(data)

            time.sleep(.5)
            w.close()
            inp = None
            print "closed"

start()
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this? I cannot figure this one out.

**Testing:**
These actions result in the same static audio file:

- Terminating the script while the button is pressed
- Terminating the script after having pressed the button once
- Terminating the script after pressing the button twice
- Replacing the button press with a loop counter and record if loop count is between 20 and 40 to make sure the button is not the issue.

**Error with numpy**

```
File "buttonWhilePressedLight.py", line 43, in <module>
start()
File "buttonWhilePressedLight.py", line 34, in start
a = numpy.fromstring(data, dtype='int16')
ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size
```

**"print l" while in the loop with numpy commented out**

```
started
inp setup
wave setup
940
-32
940
-32
940
<-etc,etc,etc->
closed
```

Comment: What testing have you done?  Have you tried pressing the button and then terminating the script while the button is still pressed?  Have you tried pressing the button and releasing it (once) and then terminating the script?  … … …  I don’t know Python, so I don’t know whether this is significant, but: the second time you press the button, the script calls `inp = alsaaudio.PCM(…)` and `w = wave.open('test.wav', 'w')` for a second time, without ever having cleaned up from the first initialization.  … … … …  Also, you have two `hasRecorded = True` statements; it seems like you need only one.

Comment: Perhaps the read of the button state takes too long and the audio gets overrun. You could time how long the poll takes by calling `time.time()` before and after and taking the difference. It is the float number of seconds.

Comment: You may get more help on the [raspberrypi specific](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange site.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! @Scott - I have added the tests that I have performed to the main post.

Comment: @meuh - to make sure the button is not the culprit I did a test with a loop counter. This gave the same result.

Comment: Why don't you explicitly close `w`? In the first example `w` is written to and then the script exits this will force the flushing of the write buffer; the second script isn't so lucky.

Comment: 1. Put a print statement in the code that initializes `inp` and `w` to make sure it's only called once per button press. 2. In your `hasRecorded == True and shouldRecord == False` branch, i.e., after recording, call `w.close()`.

Comment: Thanks. I have modified my script to close w. I have also added some prints to make sure the init only happens once. This is the case. Even with w now properly closed it still generates static.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Replacing the button test with a loop counter was going to be my next suggestion. I believe that it's time to go the KISS (Keep It Simple, Sir) route: initialize `shouldRecord` to `True` and remove (comment out) all the code that modifies it. If it works then, I'm pretty much stumped, except to say that it might have something to do with starting the recording at a time other than the start of program execution. If it *still* fails, then tear it apart, line by line, until you've reverted it to the first program. When it starts working, you'll know where the problem is.

Comment: @Scott - Thanks again. I have spend a few hours messing with the code. It is now more structured and readable, I have edited the original post. Stripping it down as much as I could, which pretty much gave me the first script, that worked. But as soon as I put the actual start/stop logic in it starts giving me static. Numpy does give an error back. Commenting the numpy out gives the file containing static.

Comment: The Numpy error means that you gave it an odd number of bytes, which it can't convert to a whole number of 16 bit samples.

Comment: The fact that the data is an odd length  points to something strange going on with the `read` call, which is supposed to return a full `periodsize` worth of bytes.   What happens if you print `l` in each loop?

Comment: @AShelly - Thank you for responding. I have updated the main post with the l output. I do not know what to make of this to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling read fast enough.  `-32` is the unix error code -`EPIPE`.<sup>*</sup>   The [Alsa docs](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/pcm.html) say:

> -EPIPE
>
> This error means xrun (underrun for playback or overrun for capture). ...  The overrun can happen when an application does not take new captured samples in time from alsa-lib.

So the sound device is generating samples faster then you are consuming them.   Adding the button `digitalRead` to your working loop has slowed it down too much.    You have set up ALSA to generate blocks of 1024 samples at 44100 samples/second, meaning you need to call `read` 
every 23 milliseconds.  I would time an empty loop reading the button and see how long it takes.

Depending on the speed of the button code, there are several possible solutions.  Lowering the sample rate will definitely reduce the frequency at which you need to call `read`, but will also reduce audio quality.  Increasing the periodsize will fill bigger buffers, meaning you need to read them less frequently.  The drawback is less responsiveness to the button press.  Using 8 bit samples may also reduce processing load at the cost of quality.

A structural solution would be to get rid of the button read in this loop, and just monitor an event, which you could set in an interrupt handler, or independent thread which monitors the I/O.

<sup>*</sup>As an aside, this appears to be either a gap in the [pyalsaaudio documentation](https://larsimmisch.github.io/pyalsaaudio/libalsaaudio.html), or a bug in the implementation.  There is no mention that the `read` function can ever return an error code.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! That gives me something new to research.

Comment: @JohnHeroHD You can find an example of reading a gpio in a separate thread using the `threading` library on page 132 of the [raspberry pi manual](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/Raspberry_Pi_Education_Manual.pdf)

Comment: I just made it work! I am spawning a new process to handle the recording and simply terminate the process once the button is no longer pressed. I even added some LED's for visual indications. Thank you all so much for pointing me in this direction! For anyone who is interested, here is the final, working script: https://gist.github.com/JohnHeroHD/c53efdae55faf780f79b